# Дюрбе или «дюрбе»?

Tags: выбор-слов

Предложение:

*Речь идёт о гробницах «дюрбе Диляры-бикеч», «северное дюрбе» и «южное дюрбе».*

Нужны ли вообще кавычки, дюрбе - это гробница, мавзолей по-крымскотатарски. И ещё: нужно ли писать с большой буквы «северное» и «южное»? Склоняюсь, что нет. Местоположение гробницы, и всего-то.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что раз слово "гробница" есть и на русском, то кавычки нужны, потому что далее приводится нерусское название. А чтобы избежать кавычек, я бы просто убрал слово "гробницы":

*Речь идёт о дюрбе Диляры-бикеч, северном дюрбе и южном дюрбе.*

Чтобы русскому читателю по-прежнему было понятно, что такое "дюрбе", можно первый раз указать в скобках, что это гробница: *Речь идёт о дюрбе (гробнице) Диляры-бикеч...*

Comment: Так ведь русскоязычный читатель тогда не поймет, что такое дюрбе...

Comment: Ну тогда есть ещё вариант указать первый раз в скобках, что это гробница.